# Problema al compilar mis archivos Sass, las clases se modifican

Tags: plugin, webpack, sass

Estoy usando webpack y al compilar los archivos sass las clases se modifican así

```
.margen-arriba-grande___-OnzA {
  margin-top: 5rem; 
}
.margen-arriba-mediano___3OWjZ { 
 margin-top: 3rem; 
}
```

pero las clases originales tendrían que ser así

```
.margen-arriba-grande {  
margin-top: 5rem; }
.margen-arriba-mediano { 
 margin-top: 3rem; 
}
```

y esta es mi configuración de webpack, alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo?

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
module.exports = {
entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/js/index.js'],
output : {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "index.html",
        template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use: [{
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
              },
              {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                  sourceMap: true,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                }
              },
              "sass-loader"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado setear la opción **modules** a **false** en el css-loader? Seteándola a false no debería añadirte nada en los selectores de clase:

```
options: {
  *******
  modules: false,
  *******
}
```